# Euler Lagrange equation $-u''=f(u)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, euler-lagrange-equation

Let $I\subseteq \mathbb R$ be an interval, $L=L(u,u',x)\in C^1(\mathbb R^3,\mathbb R)$ and $F[u]=\int_I L(u,u',x)dx$ for $u\in C^2(\mathbb R)$. Then the Euler Lagrange equation for the function $F$ is $-[\partial u' L(u,u',x)]'+\partial u L(u,u',x)=0$.
Now let $f\in C(\mathbb R)$. Determine a functional $F$ of the above form so that the ODE $-u''=f(u)$ is the Euler-Lagrange equation for $F$. Does anyone has a hint how to start here? I think I have to determine $L$.

Comment: Take the Lagrangian $L = \frac{1}{2}(u')^2 + F(u)$, where $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$. Note that $L$ correspond to the Lagrangian of classical mechanics, which gives rise to Newton's second law for the force $-f$.

Comment: @Abezhiko I get $-[\partial u'L(u',u,x)]'+\partial u L(u,u',x)=-u''+f(u)u'$ but I need $-u''-f(u)=0$

Comment: Indeed, I inverted the sign in front of $F$, but otherwise $\partial_{u'}F(u) = 0$ and $\partial_uF(u) = f(u) \neq f(u)u'$.